# How do you load a case_id into a form

Tags: commcare

I've setup case management in my application. Now I would like to load the selected case's id into the Calculate Condition of one of my hidden variables. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the session instance path to get the currently selected case's case_id (see [CommCare Session Instance help page](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/CommCare+Session+Instance)):

instance('commcaresession')/session/data/case_id

The link above also describes the syntax to load other session user or device data.